# Knockout.js: multiple bindings (related or unrelated) data-bind syntax

Tags: knockout.js

I'm a beginner with Knockout.js and i'm trying using a custom binding but something it's not clear to me. Let's suppose i realize 2 custom binding with names "color" and "innerText". The first one ("color") applies a border color to element and the second one set innerText of element (let's forget for a moment about build-in "text" binding...i know it exists). In my custom binding innerText i can accept a "color" option **for setting text color**. Now if i write:

```
<div data-bind="innerText: 'Hi everybody', color: 'Red'"></div>
```

how does Knockout know what to do with "color"? I use color in my custom-binding "innerText" as an option and I get value using allBindingsAccessor but how does knockout know it's a related binding and not another binding for border-color to apply in sequence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, if there was another binding called `color`, then it would be executed with the value that you pass to it, even if you used it from within your `innerText` binding via `allBindingsAccessor`.

So, Knockout does not do anything special, other than that it does not throw an error if you specify a bindingHandler that does not exist, as you may simply be using it as an option to another binding.

The other pattern that you can use is to pass an options object to your custom binding like:

`data-bind="innerText: { data: 'Hi everybody', color: Red }"`

Comment: Thanks, i supposed a behavior as you describe....I'll prefer use pattern you suggest to avoid ambiguities.